# Does arithmetic overflow overwrite data?

Tags: c++, binary, language-lawyer, unsigned, integer-overflow

```cpp
std::uint8_t x = 256; //Implicitly converts to 0

std::uint8_t y = 255;
y++;
```

For x, I assume everything is handled because `100000000` gets converted to `00000000` using some defined conversion from `int` to `uint8_t`. `x`'s memory should be `0 00000000` not `1 00000000`.

However with `y` I believe the overflow stays in memory. `y` is initially `11111111`. After adding 1, it becomes `1 00000000`. This wraps around back to `0` because `y` only looks at the 8 LSB.

Does the `1` after `y++;` stay in memory, or is it discarded when the addition is done?
If it is there, could it corrupt data before `y`?

Comment: After `y++` `y` becomes 0. There is no "carry" out to another byte.

Comment: `y` only has 8 bits by definition. There is nowhere for the overflow bit to be stored. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hell, no.    the additional `1` that you describe never exists in memory.   Practically, it doesn't even exist in machine circuits.    When incrementing the last binary digit, no carry bit is produced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does arithmetic overflow overwrite data?

The behaviour of signed arithmetic overflow is undefined. It's neither guaranteed to overwrite data, nor guaranteed to not overwrite data.

> ```
> std::uint8_t y = 255;
> y++;
> ```

Unsigned overflow is well defined. `y` will be 0, and there are no other side-effects.

---

Citation from the C++ standard (latest draft):

> [basic.fundamental]
>
> ... The range of representable values for the unsigned type is 0 to 2<sup>N</sup>−1 (inclusive); **arithmetic for the
> unsigned type is performed modulo 2<sup>N</sup>.**
>
> [Note 2: Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow.
> Overflow for signed arithmetic yields undefined behavior ([expr.pre]).
> — end note]
>
> ---
>
> [expr.pre]
>
> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, **the behavior is undefined.**

Since unsigned arithmetic is modular, the result can never be outside of representable values.

Comment: Citation please.

Comment: @user207421 For which part?

Comment: Err, all of it?

Comment: @user207421 Sure, I'll add the [language-lawyer] tag and look it up.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows should suffice.

Comment: But NB 'unsigned overflow' is not 'well defined'. Instead it is defined away not to exist.

Comment: @user207421 Sure; that's technically how the rules are worded. But it's hard for beginners to understand it that way, in my experience.

Comment: You should mention that "overwriting data" (in OP's sense) never happens in practice.

Answer (score 0):

When using gcc with optimizations enabled, unless one uses the -fwrapv compiler option, integer overflow may arbitrarily disrupt program behavior, leading to memory corruption, even in cases where the result of the computation that overflowed would not be used.  Reading through the published Rationale, it seems unlikely that the authors of the Standard would have expected a general-purpose compiler for a commonplace platform to behave in such fashion, but the Standard makes no attempt to anticipate and forbid all the gratuitously nonsensical ways implementations might process things.